# Size of post too big

Tags: php, post

I got a database that currently is pretty big (and even gets bigger by time).
I got a webpage on which I present the data in a form, so it can be changed.
I send it with method post.
This worked pretty well until the data got too much. Now it tells me 'it exceeds the limit of 1000'.
I read that I could change `post_max_size` in `php.ini` but I cant do it on my webserver, so its not really an option for me. Is there anything else I can do? The problem is, that ALL THE SHOW data will be in post, not only the changed one. Is there something that would do the trick?

Comment: Rework your application so it only posts data relevant to the changes the user has made.

Comment: Even if you were to manage to accommodate ever-growing POST sizes, if you continue posting your entire dataset, your application will just perform slower as the database grows in size.

Comment: its not really my application but the backend to managae to the data. so i could live with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the type and setup of your web-server, but `post_max_size` can be set in an `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value post_max_size 10000
```

Alternatively you could only send the values that have changed. If you use ajax to post your form, you could set - and check for - for example a data attribute like `modified` set on the fields.

By the way, I am assuming that you are talking about individual posts and are not sending your whole database back-and-forth. If you offer editing of a collection of items, you should use something like pagination to limit the number to a fixed maximum.

Comment: okay thats what I thought. i just liked the idea of having all on one page but thats stupid i guess.